# Angular 9 - Always add an "/" in front of the styles.css path in index.html after building --prod

Tags: angular

I am looking for a way to tell angular it should always put a slash in front of the path for the styles in the index.html when building in production.
I need that to fix a bug from a package which wont work otherwise. So currently I am fixing it manually at the moment like this

```
...
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.67b074ecf30df99829ee.css">
</head>
```

```
...
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.67b074ecf30df99829ee.css">
</head>
```

How can I do this automatically when building for production ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you can get it done using an [`npm-script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) in your `package.json`, but there's probably a better Angular/webpack way of doing it.

In `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "my-build": "ng build --prod && node prepend_slashes.js"
  }
}
```

And then in `prepend_slashes.js` you can use something like [cheerio.js](https://cheerio.js.org/) to manipulate your HTML file and replace all the occurences you're looking for.

You can then run your script using `npm my-build`.

Here's a small example to get you started:

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');

const indexFilePath = './path/to/build/index.html';

// Read `index.html`
fs.readFile(indexFilePath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }

    // Load `index.html` into cheerio object.
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    // Use jquery-like syntax to manipulate cheerio object.
    // Find all links whose href starts with `styles.`
    $("link[href^='styles.']").each(function() {
      // Prepend the /
      $(this).attr('href', '/' + $(this).attr('href'));
    })
    // Overwrite the index file.
    fs.writeFile(indexFilePath, $.html(), function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log('Successfully rewrote', indexFilePath);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I think something is missing. I am logging the actual change with the / but the file afterwards is still missing it. Do I have to save it somehow afterwards?

Comment: Oh, right!!! Yes sorry, you have to overwrite the file ;p I've updated my answer :)